# Recover hdfs metadata without namenode backup

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hortonworks-data-platform

I'm running a hadoop (hortonworks) cluster with 2 namenodes and 11 datanodes. Due to some error my namenodes where not able to start anymore. [This link](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/196904/both-name-node-are-down.html?page=2&pageSize=10&sort=votes) suggested to format these namenodes as I did and they were indeed able to start again. But when I now look into hdfs I see that my old data is gone and a new namespace was created from scratch. I haven't took a backup of the fsimage and it is lost on both namenodes due to the formatting. I have found a fsimage from 8 months old but in the meantime a lot of data is added and at that point in time we only had 6 datanodes.

The old data is still on the datanodes in the old namespace.

My question is now:
**Is there a way to recover my old data by recreating the namespace from the datanodes? Either by starting from this 6 month old fsimage or by starting completely from scratch?**

I do know now that I should for backup my namespaces. Too bad I had to learn it the hard way.

Comment: Do you have a Secondary Name Node?  How long do you maintain HDFS logs?

Comment: The 2 namenodes are in high availability mode and both got formatted.. I do have all logs from now till 6 months ago , can I use these to reconstruct the namespace?

Comment: Do you see any edit logs?  You might recover some data if you have the edit logs.